# Creating TypeDescryption of Array in ByteBuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I want to create classes like this in Byte-Buddy:

```
class A{
   public B b;
}

class B{
 public A[] a_array;
}
```

this is my code on how I imagine it could be done:

```
InstrumentedType arrayType = InstrumentedType.Default.of("[A", 
                        TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.rawType(Object.class).build(),
                        Modifier.PUBLIC);

        DynamicType.Unloaded B_made = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("B")
                .defineField("a_array", arrayType, Modifier.PUBLIC)
                .make();


        DynamicType.Unloaded A_made = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("A")
                .defineField("b", B_made.getTypeDescription(), Modifier.PUBLIC).make();

        Class A = A_made.include(B_made).load(Test.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
        Class B = A.getField("b").getType();

        System.out.println(B.getField("a_array"));
```

But this does not work even though Byte-Buddy will make the classes and load the them.

This code gives me this when evaluating `B.getField("a_array")`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: L[A;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getField0(Class.java:2975)
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1701)
    at Test.main(Test.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [A
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.findClass(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:396)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 5 more
```

I was wondering how can I fix this?

is it even possible for me to create TypeDescription of `[A` from TypeDescription of `A`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct an array type, use `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder` which allows for creating array representations. Do not use `InstrumentedType.Default` for creating arrays as they are intended to represent definable types.